# Como pegar uma String do JSON e exibir na recyclerview sem repetição?

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

Tenho um json com uma lista de usuários, fotos postadas por esse usuário.
A ideia é ter um recyclerview com o nome do usuários, e quando clicado, ele exibirá as fotos desse usuário.

A estrutura é assim:

```
{
"stories": [
        {
            "story_id": 1,
            "username": "pedroGC",
            "imagem": "url1.jpg"
},
         {
            "story_id": 2,
            "username": "tiagoFB",
            "user_id": "url2.jpg"
},
         {
            "story_id": 3,
            "username": "pedroGC",
            "user_id": "url3.jpg"
         }
      ]

}
```

**Duvida numero 01:**

Há como capturar os usernames sem repetir e exibir na recyclerview?
Tipo, pedroGC aparece duas vezes no JSON, a ideia é exibir uma lista de usuários que postaram fotos, assim, nesse exemplo seria exibido apenas pedroGB e tiaboFB no recyclerview.

**Duvida numero 02:**

Há como fazer um array com todas imagens do usuário clicado para ser exibido, a partir do onclick do recyclerview?

Exemplo: Se clicar no pedroGC, juntar as duas urls num Array (criei um "slider" que pega as fotos a partir de um array de Strings, o problema é criar essa array).

Eu já consegui exibir os 3 usuarios num recyclerview, e quando clicado era exibida a foto, o que eu quero, talvez seja algo demasiado complexo, mas é exibir apenas uma vez o usuário, e quando clicado, ele pegar todos os objetos que contem esse usuário e fazer um array com as Strings.

A mudança deve partir do adaptador, da classe modelo, ou da activity que irá exibir as imagens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode agrupar os registros de acordo com um dos campos.

Se você tem como api mínima 24+, dá pra usar streams:

```
List<Story> stories = Arrays.asList(
    new Story(1L, "pedroGC", "url1.jpg"),
    new Story(2L, "tiagoFB", "url2.jpg"),
    new Story(3L, "pedroGC", "url3.jpg")
);

Map<String, List<Story>> groupedByStream = stories
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.username));
```

Caso contrário, dá pra usar uma lib ou fazer na mão mesmo:

```
public Map<String, List<Story>> groupByUsername(List<Story> stories) {
  Map<String, List<Story>> output = new HashMap<>();

  for (Story story : stories) {
    String nome = story.username;

    List<Story> userStories;
    if(output.containsKey(nome)) {
      userStories = output.get(nome);
    } else {
      userStories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    userStories.add(story);
    output.put(nome, userStories);

  return grouped;

}
...
...
Map<String, List<Story>> customGroup = groupByUsername(stories);
```

Desta forma você vai ter um Map onde as chaves são os nomes dos usuários e os valores são as stories de cada usuário.

A desvantagem é que pra listar os usuários num recyclerview, você vai precisar acessar as chaves do map através de um index. Mas dá pra criar um list com as chaves.

O adapter ficaria mais ou menos desta forma:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

  List<String> usersByIndex;
  Map<String, List<Story>> groupedStories;


  public MyAdapter(Map<String, List<Story>> groupedStories) {
    this.groupedStories = groupedStories;
    this.usersByIndex = new ArrayList<>(groupedStories.keySet());
  }

  @Override
  public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Pego o nome do usuário pelo index do adapter
    String username = usersByIndex.get(position);

    // Pego as stories pelo nome do usuário
    List<Story> userStories = groupedStories.get(username);

    holder.setUserStories(username, userStories);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return usersByIndex.size();
  }

  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...

    public void setUserStories(String username, List<Story> userStories) {
        // Dentro do ViewHolder tenho acesso ao username e aos stories
    }

  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Cara, você é um gênio! Depois de receber do meu professor um "isso não é possível, você vai ter que refazer a api no lado do servidor" eu já estava desanimando com o projeto, mas você não só me mostrou o caminho, como me deu uma aula de Colletions. Muito obrigado mesmo! Fiz as adaptações do adapter para meu código, e o único problema que estou enfrentando é pra acessar a lista de stories de cada usuário pelo onclick, já está aparecendo apenas 2 usuários no recyclerview, mas quando clico, mostra apenas a primeira foto postada por eles. Mas creio que isso seja problema da minha classe Model.